# How is 'der' being used in this sentence from a book?

Tags: relative-clause

My German summer read from school includes this sentence:

> Wenn ich nach meinem Beruf gefragt werde, werde ich unsicher: Ich werde rot, stammle, ich, **der** ich sonst als ein sicherer Mensch bekannt bin.

How is "der" being used here? Is it referring to "der Beruf" or something else? When I Google Translated it translated to something like "...who I..." but I don't understand why an article can have that meaning.

Can the other articles be used this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not an article here. *Der* can also be a demonstrative or relative pronoun, and in this example *der ich* is the somewhat rare case of a first-person relative pronoun.

Here is a full table of male relative pronouns in all persons and numbers:

> ich, *der ich* sonst als ein sicherer Mensch bekannt bin
>   du, *der du* sonst als ein sicherer Mensch bekannt bist
>   er, *der* sonst als ein sicherer Mensch bekannt ist
>   wir, *die wir* sonst als sichere Menschen bekannt sind
>   ihr, *die ihr* sonst als sichere Menschen bekannt seid
>   sie, *die* sonst als sichere Menschen bekannt sind

Everything except for the third person is quite rare and feels somewhat awkward, but the other option (namely, talking about oneself in the third person: *ich, der als sicherer Mensch bekannt ist*) is awkward, too.

Sometimes, you will find the third-person relative pronoun extended with a personal pronoun in a similar way:

> er, *der er* sonst als ein sicherer Mensch bekannt ist

Comment: Just to add: usually, "der" can be replaced by "welcher" in where cases - which is closer to the English "who", if that is of any help...

Comment: I don't agree in one point. "ich, der sonst als..." is not awkward at all and quite common, too.

Comment: @Gerhard... "ich, welcher (ich)  sonst", "du, welcher (du) sonst"? That doesn't sound very idiomatic to me.

Comment: Always fascinating differences. :-) Regarding _welcher_, I'd say it is certainly possible, but obsolescent as a relative pronoun.

Comment: Und wenn der Sprecher eine Frau ist? Müsste es dann nicht heißen "Ich, die ich..." ?

Comment: @guidot: Ja, genau. Ich sage oben ausdrücklich, daß ich _a full table of **male** relative pronouns_ gebe.

Comment: So you can use "der" and "die" to refer to yourself, like an additional pronoun other than 'I/ich' or "you/du"? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is easier to understand if you insert "ein Mensch": ... ich,
ein Mensch, der sonst als ein sicherer Mensch bekannt ist. "der" is here a relative pronoun as already said above.

Comment: That does help with understanding, thank you!

Comment: @AlexD - When an answer is helpful you can show this by clicking on the arrow head to the left of the post.