# Understanding the cases of nouns and pronouns in Kafka’s ‘Der Verschollene’

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, pronoun

The question is on the dass-clause in this excerpt from a long speech by Karl Rossmann in Kafka’s *Der Verschollene.*

> Was für Bedenken er [Karls Onkel] gegen diesen Besuch hatte, ist ja jetzt gleichgültig, ich weiß bloß ganz bestimmt, daß nichts in diesem Bedenken war, was **Sie**,<sup>1</sup> **Herr**<sup>2</sup> Pollunder, kränken könnte, **der**<sup>3</sup> **Sie**<sup>4</sup> der beste, der allerbeste Freund meines Onkels sind. Kein anderer kann sich in der Freundschaft meines Onkels auch nur im Entferntesten mit Ihnen vergleichen.

Am I right to understand it in this way?

1. *Sie* is in the accusative and the object of *kränken*.
2. *Herr* is in the vocative (‘O! Mr. Pollunder’).  Alternatively it could have been *Herrn*, which would be in the accusative and an apposition to *Sie*.
3. *der* is a relative pronoun in the nominative (referring to *Herr Pollunder*).
4. *Sie* could be either (a) in the nominative and an apposition to *der* or (b) in the vocative.

I realize that vocative is not part of German grammar as found in grammar books.  Maybe I should have said a vocative use of the nominative.

Comment: For _der Sie_, see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23618/how-is-der-being-used-in-this-sentence-from-a-book I didn’t think of this particular case when I wrote my answer there, but it works the same as _der du_. Note the verb in third person plural, corresponding to _Sie_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll answer your questions in the ‘logical’ order.

2. Yes, it is a vocative (not generally used as a category in German grammar and may be referred to as *vocative use of nominative* etc. instead). You could instead use the accusative case, in which case it would be an apposition but I feel that sounds less polite, since it explicitly does not vocatively address Mr Pollunder.

I need to reset numbering.

1. Since we have established the *Herr* bit, we can leave out the bits in the commas giving us:

   > […], was Sie kränken könnte, […]

   This is a normal relative clause where *was* is the the subject (compare the verb form) and *Sie* thus must be accusative object.

Another reset required.

3. *Der* is indeed a relative pronoun introducing a relative clause which refers to a masculine noun that takes nominative case in the relative clause. No surprises.
4. As Chirlu stated in his [related answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/23619/15318) the appended *Sie* is merely a way used to override the third person singular of *der* and to allow the following sentence to use the ‘natural’ verb forms.

The fourth answer may require some explanation. *Sie* cannot be an apposition since that would need to be enclosed in a pair of commas if I understood the punctuation rules correctly. It is also not a vocative in the strict sense. It does not enhance the address of Mr Pollunder but is there for grammatical and syntactical reasons.

*Sie* is also *strictly* connected to *der:* It cannot be moved away.

> <del>[…], der der beste Freund Sie sind.</del>

If we had a moveable *Sie* right behind the *der* it would *have* to be an independent part of the sentence; usually that would mean accusative case and being an object.

> […], der Sie{acc} mir vorgestellt hat.
>
> […], der mir Sie{acc} vorgestellt hat.

Cases with *Sie* in nominative are rare but possible:

> […], der Sie{nom} heute sind.
>
> […], der heute Sie{nom} sind. (Contains a high amount of tension.)

The purpose of the *Sie* affixed to the relative pronoun is to redefine the relative clause’s subject. It is possible to leave it out, but then the sentence would be:

> […], der der beste Freund **ist.**

It is weird switching between a formal third person plural (*Sie*) to third person singular just because of a relative clause. The inserted *Sie* basically overrides the *der* and governs the verb’s numerus. Inserting other pronouns can even govern the person in question:

> […], der ich der beste Freund **bin.**

And all of this is merely a verbose form of Chirlu’s already linked answer.